# Running tasks defined in my grunt plugin: Task not found

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to take some tasks that I've written in Grunt files for a project and make a re-usable Grunt plugin. I've been struggling to find some docs that show how to do this end-to-end, but am making slow progress. In very brief, my plugin will take an HTML SWIG template, and localize it to a bunch of different locales, as specified by a CSV file. (There are a few other steps, but I'm trying to keep it simple for this post).

I'm using grunt v0.4.5, and I used grunt-init and cloned the grunt-plugin repo as described in the [official Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins). Here's what I've got so far:

```
grunt-emaillocalization/ (Plugin definition)
 - Gruntfile.js
 - package.json
 - tasks/
   - emaillocalization.js
   - bin/
     - convertCSVtoJSONForSWIG.js
     - makeEmailImages.js
```

Here's the plugin definition Gruntfile.js. It makes use of a plugin called [grunt-swig-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-swig-localization#grunt-swig-static-localized-html-generator). Simplified for brevity:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    emaillocalization: {
      default_options: {
        options: {
          csvFile: 'config/emaillocalization/email.csv',
          templatesDir: 'config/emaillocalization'
        }
      }
    },

    swigLocalization: {
      main: {
        src: ['<%= emaillocalization.default_options.templatesDir %>/templates/*.swig', 'tmp/emaillocalization/json/*.json'],
        outputDir: 'dist/emaillocalization'
      }
    },

    /* Snip some other stuff */

  });

  // Actually load this plugin's task(s).
  grunt.loadTasks('tasks');

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-swig-localization');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');

};
```

Here's the plugin definition tasks/emaillocalization.js task definition, again simplified for brevity:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.registerMultiTask('emaillocalization', 'Localizes email templates using a CSV as input.', function() {
    /* Snip setting some parameters */
    var taskList = ['emailprep', 'emailcsv2json', 'swigLocalization', 'copy:copyEmailImageFiles', 'shell:emailImages', 'replace:emailImageURLPrefix'];
    grunt.task.run(taskList);
  });

  /* Snip some other tasks */

};
```

If I run **grunt emaillocalization** from the plugin definition repo, it does everything it's supposed to; all the tasks get processed.

The package.json file in the package definition contains the following, to force the swigLocalization plugin to be bundled with an npm install:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-swig-localization": "~0.1.0"
  },
```

Now in my project's repo, I'm including my grunt-emaillocalization plugin in the package.json thus:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...,
    "grunt-emaillocalization": "git@bitbucket.org:mycompany/grunt-emaillocalization.git"
  }
```

Then in the project's repo's Gruntfile.js, I'm definining it as follows:

```
*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require("load-grunt-tasks")(grunt);
  require("time-grunt")(grunt);

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    /* Snip a whole bunch of stuff */

    emaillocalization: {
      default_options: {
        options: {
          csvFile: 'email.csv',
          templatesDir: 'misc/emaillocalization'
        },
        files: {
          'tmp/default_options': ['test/fixtures/testing', 'test/fixtures/123']
        }
      }
    },

    gitinfo: {}

  });

  /* Snip a whole bunch of project registerTasks */

  grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-emaillocalization');

};
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The place I'm stuck is that when I run grunt emaillocalization.js *from the project repo* (i.e. I try to actually *use* my plugin), I get this error:

> Warning: Task "swigLocalization" not found. Use --force to continue.

**DEBUGGING**

From within my plugin source, if I run **grunt --help**, swigLocalization is listed as an available task.

From within my project, where I'm using my plugin, if I run **npm list** the grunt-swig-localization plugin, which provides the swigLocalization task) certainly seems to be available:

```
├─┬ grunt-emaillocalization@0.1.0
│ └─┬ grunt-swig-localization@0.1.0
│   └─┬ swig@1.1.0
│     ├─┬ optimist@0.6.0
│     │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
│     └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.0
│       ├── async@0.2.10
│       ├─┬ optimist@0.3.7
│       │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
│       ├─┬ source-map@0.1.43
│       │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
│       └── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I found the solution.

Firstly, the Gruntfile.js in the plugin definition is ignored when the task is run as a plugin in another project. So the configuration for any bundled plugins must be set procedurally in the plugin's task file. Here's my simplified, working tasks/emaillocalization.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var path = require('path');

  grunt.task.loadTasks(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/grunt-swig-localization/tasks'));

  grunt.registerMultiTask('emaillocalization', 'Localizes email templates using a CSV as input.', function() {
    /* Snip setting some parameters */
    var taskList = ['emailprep', 'emailcsv2json', 'generateHtmlFiles:'+this.options().templatesDir /* other tasks */];
    grunt.task.run(taskList);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('generateHtmlFiles', 'Create HTML files from JSON and template', function (src) {
    var templatePath = path.resolve(src) + path.sep + '*.swig';
    var jsonPath = path.resolve('tmp/emaillocalization/json') + path.sep + '*.json';
    // TIP: Don't resolve path for this.
    var outputPath = 'dist/emaillocalization';

    grunt.config.set('swigLocalization', {
      main: {
        src: [templatePath, jsonPath],
        outputDir: outputPath
      }
    });
    var taskList = ['emailprep', 'swigLocalization'];
    grunt.task.run(taskList);
  });

  /* Snip other tasks */
};
```

The key points for using 3rd-party tasks in your own plugin I found were:

1. Ensure that your dependent plugins are setup as dependencies in your package.json, and not devDependencies. This ensures they'll get installed when you run npm install when you use your plugin. (I was already doing this).
2. Move all the configuration from the plugin's Gruntfile.js to the plugin's task file, adding wrapper tasks as needed, and set it procedurally using [grunt.config.set()](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.set) just before running the task. You can read the
3. Explicitly load the tasks from the 3rd-party plugins you want to use in your task file before using them, with [grunt.task.loadTasks()](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadtasks). You will also need to use Node's [path.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) and __dirname to reference the plugins' tasks directory, relative from your plugins' task file.